# Rをバージョンアップしたら、caretでエラーが発生する

Tags: r

R(ver 3.1.1)では動作しているのですが、R(ver 3.3.1)の環境ではエラーになります。

```
tmp<-dummyVars(~days,data=data1)
predict(tmp,data1)
```

このpredictの実行で、下記のようなエラーが発生しています。

```
options(contrasts=newCntr)でエラー:'contrasts'の値が不正です
```

前述のとおり、ver 3.1.1では問題なく動作します。
パッケージが3.3.1に非対応と言う事なのでしょうか。

Comment: `sessionInfo()`追加してください

Answer (score 1):

パッケージは3.3.1に対応しています。[問題を再現可能](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)な`data1`を示すとより良い回答が期待できるかと？

推測ですが、`options("contrasts")` にデフォルト `c("contr.treatment", "contr.poly")` ではない値が入っているのではないでしょうか。
もしそうでしたら、`options(contrasts = c("contr.treatment", "contr.poly"))`で解決します。